# Select and use one column

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

Please consider the following (working) stored procedure. This function receives an integer as its first parameter, indicating which `privilegeid` has to be checked against the current user. Privileges are stored in the table `privileges` and consist of an id and a name (varchar).

Each privilege belongs to one or more `roles` stored in `users_roles`. Each user is assigned to one or more roles. This function retrieves all roles assigned to `current_user` and checks them, like said, against the given priviligeid.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."has_privilege" (in int4) RETURNS bool AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    asked_privilegeid ALIAS FOR $1;
    userid int;
    role_row users_roles%rowtype;
    privilege_row privileges%rowtype;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username=$1' INTO userid USING current_user;

    FOR role_row IN SELECT * FROM users_roles
    WHERE userid=userid 
    LOOP
    IF role_row.roleid = 1 THEN
        return TRUE;
    END IF;

    FOR privilege_row IN SELECT * FROM privileges WHERE roleid=role_row.roleid LOOP
        IF privilege_row.privilegeid = asked_privilegeid THEN
            return TRUE;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    return FALSE;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

However, this code isn't a efficient as it could be considering it retrieves *all* rowvalues for `users_roles` and `privileges`. I tried to write the procedure as following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."has_privilege" (in int4) RETURNS bool AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    asked_privilegeid ALIAS FOR $1;
    privilegeid int;
    userid int;
    roleid int;

    //role_row users_roles%rowtype;
    //privilege_row privileges%rowtype;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username=$1' INTO userid USING current_user;

    FOR roleid IN SELECT roleid FROM users_roles
    WHERE userid=userid 
    LOOP
    IF roleid = 1 THEN
        return TRUE;
    END IF;

    FOR privilegeid IN SELECT privilegeid FROM privileges WHERE roleid=roleid LOOP
        IF privilegeid = asked_privilegeid THEN
            return TRUE;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    return FALSE;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: The indentions didn't came through as expected. Here are pastebin links:
http://pastebin.com/w18WaCW0 
http://pastebin.com/W8ewXxEe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the row

```
WHERE userid=userid
```

It is ambiguous which is the column from the table and which is your variable.  Same issue here

```
FROM privileges WHERE roleid=roleid
```

Don't use variable names that are also column names that you will reference

You can also rewrite your PROC body as a direct SQL statement that will probably work faster

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."has_privilege" (in int4) RETURNS bool AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    asked_privilegeid ALIAS FOR $1;
BEGIN

RETURN EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN users_roles r on r.userid=u.userid
    LEFT JOIN privileges p on p.roleid=r.roleid
       AND p.privilegeid = asked_privilegeid
       AND r.roleid <> 1 //  don't need to process this join if we already have our answer
    WHERE u.username = $1
      AND (r.roleid=1 OR p.privilegeid is not null))

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Comment: As I'm by no means an SQL-expert, I'm still trying to understand your code. I'm wondering about the `FROM users u` part. Shouldn't this raise an error?

Comment: @Mzialla - sorry! Just providing an alternative, if it doesn't work, stick to the (fixed) original. You can try the query outside of the proc easily (change RETURN to SELECT). EXISTS returns true for any row found.  It joins users to users_roles and optionally to privileges joined properly.  If r.role_id is 1, it doesn't even attempt to join to privileges and the AND condition at the end will return true. If the roleid is not one, it continues to search for privileges for that role matching the asked_privilegeid.  If this succeeds, the OR at the end causes `true` to be returned.

Comment: No need to apology, I really appreciate your effort! Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE
    asked_privilegeid ALIAS FOR $1;
    _userid int; -- chage to avoid variable name same as column name
    role_row users_roles%rowtype;
    privilege_row privileges%rowtype;
BEGIN
    _userid := (select userid from users where username = session_user); -- if u use current_user u will have problem when function is defined as security definer

    FOR role_row IN SELECT * FROM users_roles WHERE userid = _userid -- your code is error becus userid is same as your variable name
    LOOP
    IF role_row.roleid = 1 THEN
        return TRUE;
    END IF;

    FOR privilege_row IN SELECT * FROM privileges WHERE roleid=role_row.roleid LOOP
        IF privilege_row.privilegeid = asked_privilegeid THEN
            return TRUE;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    return FALSE;
END
```

when u declare variable in postgre, it is good practice that u use underscore b4 variable name '_userid'. to make it distinct from column name

Comment: Thanks for the comment on `session_user`!

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be solved with just a single SELECT statement:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM privileges p
  JOIN roles r ON r.privilegeid = p.privilegeid 
  JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.roleid = r.roleid
  JOIN users u ON u.userid = ur.userid AND u.username = session_user
WHERE p.privilegeid = asked_privilegeid
```

(not tested)

If the count is zero, the privilege is not assigned, otherwise it is.

Comment: There is also the special case of roleid=1 (I guess = admin/all access). `roles` is also skipped in the proc since it is not required